# Weird MySQL query plan: why is this query using temporary & filesort? How to optimize it?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM amp_ads,amp_c,amp_c_countries    
WHERE 
(amp_c.zone = '24' OR amp_c.zone = '25') AND 
amp_ads.ad_complete = '1' AND 
amp_ads.ad_type = '17' AND 
amp_ads.accept = '1' AND 
amp_ads.en_w = '1' AND 
amp_c.en_u = '1' AND 
amp_c.en_w = '1' AND 
(amp_c.i_nu>'0' OR amp_c.c_nu>'0' OR amp_c.d_valid_by>'1299341823' OR amp_c.unlimit='1') AND 
(amp_c.i_d_max='0' OR amp_c.i_d_nu>'0') AND 
(amp_c.c_d_max='0' OR  amp_c.c_d_nu>'0') AND 
amp_c.t1<'1299341823' AND 
amp_c.t2>'1299341823' AND 
amp_c.d7 = '1'  AND 
(amp_c.some_countr = '0' OR (amp_c_countries.country = 'ES' AND amp_c.n = amp_c_countries.ad AND amp_c.camp = amp_c_countries.c))  AND 
amp_c.n = amp_ads.n AND 
amp_ads.def = 0       
ORDER BY amp_c.price_c desc LIMIT 1
```

(It's actually not `SELECT *`, but I simplified the `SELECT` clause to make it less messy.)

The output of `EXPLAIN` of the above query is:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: amp_c
         type: ref
possible_keys: work,n_index,zone_price
          key: zone_price
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 79
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: amp_ads
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: n,work
          key: n
      key_len: 4
          ref: advertis_admpro.amp_c.n
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: amp_c_countries
         type: index
possible_keys: work
          key: work
      key_len: 12
          ref: NULL
         rows: 4083
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Using join buffer
```

1) Why is the 1st table `Using temporary` and `Using filesort`? `EXPLAIN` show that it is using the index `zone_price`, which is made up of 2 columns: `(zone, price_c)`. So after the index is used to select rows based on the `zone` value, all the resulting rows are in the order of price_c. And since the query is ORDER BY price_c, there should be no need for `Using temporary` and `Using filesort` at all. What am I missing?

2) For the 3rd table, it is supposed to be using the index `work`. But yet ref is `NULL`. What does that mean? `work` is made up of the columns `(ad,c,country)`. So when rows are selected from `amp_c_countries` using the `WHERE` clause `(amp_c_countries.country = 'ES' AND amp_c.n = amp_c_countries.ad AND amp_c.camp = amp_c_countries.c)`, shouldn't it be just a simple index lookup? The `rows` value in `EXPLAIN` is 4083, `amp_c_countries` has 4113 rows according to `SHOW TABLE STATUS`. Does that mean MySQL is doing a full index scan instead of a lookup?

3) Any ideas on how to fix the above 2 problems? `amp_ads` contains `TEXT` columns, so a lot of disk temp tables are being created:

```
| Created_tmp_disk_tables               | 906952      |
| Created_tmp_files                     | 11          |
| Created_tmp_tables                    | 912227      |
```

`show processlist` also shows many processes are in the state of `Copying to tmp table`.

Thanks. Appreciate your help.

**EDIT**:

Outputs of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE `advertis_admpro`.`amp_c`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: amp_c
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `amp_c` (
  `n` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `camp` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `zone` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `javascript` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `banner_target` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `accept` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `en_u` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `en_w` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `i_got` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `c_got` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `r` double(4,2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `price_i` double(10,6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `price_c` double(10,3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `i_nu` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `c_nu` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `unlimit` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d_total` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d_valid_by` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `t1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `t2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d1` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d4` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d5` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d6` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d7` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tz1` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tz2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tz3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tz4` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tz5` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `some_countr` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `i_d_max` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `c_d_max` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `i_d_nu` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `c_d_nu` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `username` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `emailed` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `work` (`en_u`,`en_w`,`i_nu`,`c_nu`,`d_valid_by`,`unlimit`,`i_d_max`,`c_d_max`,`i_d_nu`,`c_d_nu`,`t1`,`t2`,`n`),
  KEY `n_index` (`n`,`camp`),
  KEY `zone_price` (`zone`,`price_c`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE `advertis_admpro`.`amp_ads`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: amp_ads
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `amp_ads` (
  `n` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ad_type` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `accept` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `en_w` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `weight` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `w` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `h` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `norepeat` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `campaigns` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `zones` text NOT NULL,
  `keywords` text NOT NULL,
  `banner` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `alt` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `raw` text NOT NULL,
  `kind` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `javascript` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ad_complete` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `url1` text NOT NULL,
  `url2` text NOT NULL,
  `url3` text NOT NULL,
  `text1` text NOT NULL,
  `text2` text NOT NULL,
  `text3` text NOT NULL,
  `text4` text NOT NULL,
  `text5` text NOT NULL,
  `text6` text NOT NULL,
  `text7` text NOT NULL,
  `text8` text NOT NULL,
  `text9` text NOT NULL,
  `text10` text NOT NULL,
  `picture1` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `picture2` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `picture3` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `picture4` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `picture5` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `username` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `preview` text NOT NULL,
  `def` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY `n` (`n`),
  KEY `work` (`ad_type`,`accept`,`en_w`,`norepeat`,`ad_complete`,`def`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1532 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE `advertis_admpro`.`amp_c_countries`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: amp_c_countries
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `amp_c_countries` (
  `ad` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `c` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `country` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  KEY `work` (`ad`,`c`,`country`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Ordering the results will require a filesort. It doesn't mean an actual on-disk file will be used, though.

Comment: Ordering results don't always require a filesort, especially when the rows are already ordered in the index, as is the case here. Also on-disk tables ARE being used here, as shown by the Created_tmp_disk_tables value I posted.

Comment: The filesort operation is expected. It's required to satisfy the ORDER BY. Note that the index chosen by the optimizer (zone_price) does not have the price_c as the leading column, and it's possible that the query will return rows with different values of \`zone\`. So, it's not true that the rows returned will be in order by \`price_c\` (either ascending or descending).

Comment: @spencer7593 - you're right about the query returning rows with different values of 'zone'. I forgot about that. Thanks. But when I changed the query to just a single value of 'zone' (see my comments to @Galz's answer), I still got 'Using temporary, Using filesort'. Also, even when filesort is necessary, when does it need to use a temporary table? That I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prevent the need for sorting, **when sorting according to the index's second part, the first part must remain constant.**

In your case, the condition for the first part is `amp_c.zone = '24' OR amp_c.zone = '25'`, which may not be good enough.

Try changing the condition to `amp_c.zone = '24'` only, see if that changes the explain (Obviously you will not get all the results you need, but do it to validate my guess)...

If it works and the explain isn't showing *using filesort* again, you have 2 options:

1. Sort by **all** parts of the index: `ORDER BY amp_c.zone, amp_c.price_c`.
2. Have only one condition on the zone column, and union with another similar query for the second condition, something like:

---

```
(SELECT  ...  WHERE zone = 24 ... ORDER BY price_c)
UNION
(SELECT  ...  WHERE zone = 25 ... ORDER BY price_c)
ORDER BY price_c
```

Comment: I tried with just `amp_c.zone = '24'`. Unfortunately `EXPLAIN` still showed `Using temporary; Using filesort`. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @Continuation - Just found the documentation about our subject: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html. There is one more issue there which may be relevant although I am not sure how you can change your query to fix it: "You are joining many tables, and the columns in the ORDER BY are not all from the first nonconstant table that is used to retrieve rows. (This is the first table in the EXPLAIN output that does not have a const join type.)"

Comment: @Continuation - Also try to add the zone to the ORDER BY clause (before the price). This, again, isn't exactly what you are looking for but may get us closer...

Comment: I added zone to ORDER BY before price_c but still the same EXPLAIN result, Using temporary and filesort. Regarding that quote from the documentation, the first non-constant table is amp_c as shown by EXPLAIN. My column in ORDER BY -- price_c -- is from amp_c. So it should work according to the documentation. That's why I'm so baffled. Thanks.